# How do I get the population count of an unsigned unchecked number with boost::multiprecision?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost::multiprecision to have fixed but arbitrary precision integers. 
I was planning to use `number<cpp_int<W, W, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void>>`. The first obvious question is:

Does this datatype have the standard bit pattern of any unsigned integer of a given precision? I heard that signed extended precision numbers don't use 2's complement, but I think that unsigned ones should use the standard representation, or am I missing something?

If this is the case, then ho can i get the population count of the integer? I doesn't seem to be any public interface to do that. I could be happy also of a way to get the internal
memory so I can count the population of the single words used as storage.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled across this looking for the same thing. I ended up writing the following:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

// N.B.: Prior to Boost 1.79 MinBits and MaxBits were unsigned,
//       not size_t - using auto to paper over this difference.
template <
    auto MinBits,
    auto MaxBits,
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type SignType,
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type Checked,
    class Allocator>
size_t popcount(
        const boost::multiprecision::number<
            boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<
                MinBits,
                MaxBits,
                SignType,
                Checked,
                Allocator>>& bits) {
    const auto& backend = bits.backend();

    // Using std::bitset::count to access a native popcnt.
    // In principle the limb type could be larger than what a
    // bitset can natively handle, in practice it likely isn't.
    using BitsetNativeType = unsigned long long;
    constexpr size_t kNativeBits = std::numeric_limits<BitsetNativeType>::digits;
    using LimbType = std::decay_t<decltype(*backend.limbs())>;
    constexpr size_t kLimbBits = std::numeric_limits<LimbType>::digits;

    constexpr size_t kNativesToCount = (kLimbBits + kNativeBits - 1) / kNativeBits;
    constexpr size_t kShiftPerNative = kNativesToCount > 1 ? kNativeBits : 0;
    static_assert(kNativesToCount > 0, "bad bit counts");

    size_t result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != backend.size(); ++i) {
        auto limb_value = backend.limbs()[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j != kNativesToCount; ++j) {
            const std::bitset<kNativeBits> limb_bitset{BitsetNativeType(limb_value)};
            result += limb_bitset.count();
            limb_value >>= kShiftPerNative;            
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For native word sizes (i.e., <= 64 bits) this compiles to a single `popcnt`. Above that it compiles to two `popcnt` up to 128 bits. Beyond that it auto-vectorizes in clang - presumably to something inspired by [Faster Population Counts Using AVX2 Instructions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07612.pdf) but frankly I didn't investigate further. In gcc it just doesn't unroll the loop and still uses `popcnt`.

---

clang demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fve195TeM
gcc demo: https://godbolt.org/z/P4ndY8ccq

Answer (score 2):

Use `lsb` and `msb` to get the index of the least and most significant bits, then test each bit in turn with `bit_test`:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
int main() {
    constexpr unsigned W = 1024;
    number<cpp_int_backend<W, W, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void>> num;
    num = 43;
    unsigned popcount = 0;
    unsigned i = lsb(num);
    unsigned const end = msb(num);
    for (; i <= end; ++i) {
        if (bit_test(num,i) != 0) {
            ++popcount;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Population Count: " << popcount << "\n"; //Prints '4'.
}
```

Refer to the documentation for [boost::multiprecision::number](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html).

Comment: Yes, but this sounds incredibly inefficient. The popcount operation on single words can be done in one single instruction, so to calculate the popcount of a 512 bit number stored as an array of uint64_t, I'd have to do a little cycle of 8 efficient instructions. Here instead I have to do 512 steps each one probably involving masks, shifts etc... I hoped there were a more efficient way...

Comment: @gigabytes there is. however, `bmp::number<>` is a generic frontend that cannot assume implementation details. Look at libgmp/mpfr/cpp_int for backend details. Pretty sure they will make it pretty easy (access via `n.backend()`)

Comment: If you are going to do something like that, it's probably better to just use x&=x-1 to remove the last bit. Just count how many times you have to do this before x becomes 0.